I can't add an image to the site and I don't understand how to fix the error
I am trying to add an image to my site like this:
<img src="{{url_for('static,filename='img/unnamed.png')}}" alt="unnamed">

I get the following error:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'img'

How can I fix this error?

I think this is because the url_for call is a little messed up. Specifically you are missing a ' after static. Try this:
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/unnamed.png')}}" alt="unnamed">

Make sure that your filesystem looks something like this:
playground/
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── img
│       └── unnamed.png
└── templates
    └── index.html

In this case, what you really need is the static/img/unnamed file.
